# Which method would this optimization algorithm used?

Tags: r, function

If I used the build-in function `optim` without stating the `method=`, which method would this algorithm used?

```
set.seed(93420)                         # Creating random data
x <- rnorm(500)
y <- rnorm(500) + 0.7 * x
data <- data.frame(x, y)
head(data)                              # Print head of data
#             x           y
# 1 -0.21492991 -0.06814474
# 2 -0.02217756 -0.84956484
# 3  0.55175788  0.11247758
# 4 -0.33581492 -0.86346317
# 5 -0.02489514  0.44307381
# 6 -1.44784931 -2.49701457

my_function <- function(data, par) {    # Own function for residual sum of squares
  with(data, sum((par[1] + par[2] * x - y)^2))
}
optim_output <- optim(par = c(0, 1),    # Applying optim
                      fn = my_function,
                      data = data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `args`, we may see that `optim` provides five method parameters.

```
args(optim)
# function (par, fn, gr = NULL, ..., method = c("Nelder-Mead", 
#     "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN", "Brent"), lower = -Inf, 
#     upper = Inf, control = list(), hessian = FALSE)
```

In the first lines of the function code, `match.arg` was used,

```
method <- match.arg(method)
```

where

```
args(match.arg)
# function (arg, choices, several.ok = FALSE)
```

In `?match.arg` documentation, we may read

> ...default argument matching will set `arg` to `choices`, this is allowed
> as an exception to the ‘length one unless several.ok is TRUE’ rule,
> and returns the first element.

which means, since `choices=` was not used, by default `optim` uses the first element of `method`, which is `"Nelder-Mead"`.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt about a function see the documentation, `?optim`:

**Arguments**

> method: The method to be used. See ‘Details’. Can be abbreviated.

**Details**

> By default optim performs minimization, but it will maximize if
> control$fnscale is negative. optimHess is an auxiliary function to
> compute the Hessian at a later stage if hessian = TRUE was forgotten.
>
> The default method is an implementation of that of Nelder and Mead
> (1965), that uses only function values and is robust but relatively
> slow. It will work reasonably well for non-differentiable functions.

Comment: So it would use the first method in `method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
                 "Brent"),`?